# Intellij Spring MVC Cannot find bean with qualifer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to  make dependencies injection for DAO and services. But I get  stuck with an error  "cannot find  bean  for  metier". Here  is my controller code:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("metier")
private MetierInterface metierInterface;
```

And my applicationContext.xml

```xml
<bean id="dao" class="com.act.cours.dao.DaoImplement"></bean>
<bean id="metier" class="com.act.cours.metier.MetierImplement">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
```

I have interfaces DaoInterface.java, MetierInterface.java and implementing classes DaoImplement.java,  MetierImplement.java.

Comment: Can you check if your `applicationContext.xml` is loading at time of application bootup?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the part you didn't include - config file imports, component scans, etc. Also, do you really need the `@Qualifier`? If you only have one implementation of each interface it's better to depend on type autowiring instead of matching names/ids manually.

Comment: I really don't need `@qualifier`, but  i thought it would resolve the issue,  but didn't. I also  watched some tutorials about declaring application Context.xml, i found we just have to create it in  resource folder

Comment: web.xml
    `<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern><\se`

Comment: Issue resolved, i had to declare applicationContext.xml in  web.xml                                              `<init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
                classpath*:applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>`